# How to block an amp-components until other amp-component is resolved.?

Tags: amp-html, ampscript, amp-iframe

I want to block some amp-components (**amp-image**, **amp-ad**, or **amp-iframe**) until one of the amp components is resolved. ie. - amp-captcha is solved or amp-script ran successfully.

I checked that we can achieve something similar using an amp-consent component with d**ata-block-on-consent** attribute, I am wondering if we have some param to achieve this without using **amp-consent**

Comment: If not do we have any workaround to achieve this.?